# React + AJAX избыточный render компонента

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

Здравствуйте.

Для заполнения содержимого React компонента использую AJAX в теле метода componentWillMount, где меняю state по исполнении запроса. Беда в том, что  render компонента выполняется как до завершения запроса, так и после изменения состояния методом setState. Более того, если такой компонент рендерит еще один, в котором также используется AJAX, то количество вызовов render растет как степень двойки.

Как заставить компонент рендерится только после получения необходимых данных?

```
var News = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            news: [],
            page: 1
        };
    },

    componentWillMount: function () {
        let xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "server/news.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=() => {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4) return;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                this.setState({
                    news: eval(xmlhttp.responseText.toString())
                });
            } else {
                handleError(xmlhttp.statusText);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.send('page=' + this.state.page);
        var timeout = setTimeout( function(){ xmlhttp.abort(); handleError("Request time over") }, 10000);
    },

    render: function () {
        let itemList = this.state.news.map(function(item, iterator){
            return (
                <NewsItem
                    niTitle={item[0]}
                    niText={item[1]}
                    niDate={item[2]}
                    niImg={item[3]}
                    key={"ni " + iterator}
                />
            );
        });
        return (
            <div>
                {itemList}
                <PageChanger page={this.state.page}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Вопрос решен. Не удаляю, вдруг кому пригодится: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626824/react-ajax-component-over-rendering

Comment: По-хорошему перенести бы это дело в  ComponentDidMount, а пока данных нет - поставить что-то типа компонента крутилочки <Loading />

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.